# Count folders with names ending )x

Tags: batch-file, count, directory

I have a batch file which totals the number of directories:

```
for /d %%a in (*) do set /a count+=1
```

Now I need to total the directory names ending with the string **`)x`**, e.g. `Mona Lisa (1986)x`

I have tried unsuccessfully with:

```
for /d %%a in (")x") do set /a count+=1
```

Comment: `for /d %%d in (*^)x) do set /a count+=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) count the items filtered by the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html):

```cmd
dir /B /A:D "*)x" | find /C /V ""
```

Prepend or append `2> nul` to the `dir` part to suppress error messages in case no such directories exist.

To capture the resulting value and store it in a variable, use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

```cmd
for /F %%C in ('2^> nul dir /B /A:D "*)x" ^| find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%C"
echo %COUNT%
```

Answer (score 1):

`for /d %%d in (*^)x) do set /a count+=1`

You may first want to check that it finds them correctly:

`for /d %%d in (*^)x) do echo "%%~d"`

Comment: @Henrik I suggest you also add `setlocal` before the `for` loop to set the variable locally to the script only, the reason is, If you run the file from the same cmd window each time it will I increase the counter each time it is ran as `%count%` is set as an environment variable. by using setlocal, you localise the variable to the script, alternatively, just add `set "count=0"`

Comment: in the last example, you can simply do `echo %%d` as `%%~d` will strip surrounding quotes which does not exsist and then you are adding quotes as well to the echo anyway..

Comment: @AlexP: I have used your " (*^)x) " suggestion with success. And I have not been able to find documentation about the " ^ " Character. Can anybody point me in the direction?

Comment: @Henrik: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative, (the difference being that this doesn't ignore some directories, *such as hidden ones*):

```bat
For /F %%A In ('Dir /AD "*)x" 2^>Nul') Do Set "count=%%A"
```

*You should really precede this with `Set "count="`*